# isync: "SSL error connection mail.example.com... certificate has expired" but the certificate has not expired

Tags: email, ssl, mail-server, mbsync, isync

I've checked with certbot and a bunch of external diagnostic tools and everything seems fine, but I cannot sync my mailboxes.

Is there a way to trace the root of the problem? Or perhaps a way to make an exception for the email server?

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late but I stumbled upon this post while I was having the same issue.

In [a forum topic in the same research](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/openssl-shows-certificate-is-expired-but-cerbot/153680), I've heard that reloading dovecot was enough. I did it and it worked.